# "Cannot convert to multiple nodes" error message in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I'm working with repeat groups. As soon as I input a number of repeats for the repeat group to run over, I get this error:

> cannot convert multiple nodes to a raw value. Refine path expression to match only one node.

How should I begin to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repeat group number has to be a single hidden value reference (such as /data/num_children).  You cannot have a raw number like 5 and you also cannot have a calculation such as /data/num_children + 1.

Comment: Another limitation that was affecting the repeat group: repeat groups cannot have display logic, they need to be in a folder with the necessary display logic or this error will occur